# Path types in Symfony: When to use "AppBundle:SomeEntity" or "AppBundle/Entity/SomeEntity"?

Tags: php, symfony

Different Symfony docs, tutorials and howtos often use different path types to specify entities, services, etc.

For example an entity stored in `src/AppBundle/Entity/SomeEntity.php` can be referenced by `AppBundle/Entity/SomeEntity` or `AppBundle:SomeEntity` and `$em->getRepository(**entityReference**)` works with both path/reference types.

Is there a rule of thumb which type should be used when? Is there any difference or is this a matter of personal preference? Is there any manual on the path syntax used in Symfony?

BTW: I am working with Symfony 3.4. I am aware that in newer versions bundles are not used anymore. However, I think the overall questions is still the same.

Comment: `AppBundle:SomeEntity` is just an alias, they are useful if you have very long namespaces, but they don't provide anything else. You can customize it in the `doctrine.yaml` for each EntityManager. For a rule of thumb: just use the same format everywhere :)

Comment: The best way to refer it would be `SomeEntity::class`. This should work if you are using PHP 5.5 or higher

Comment: Symfony 2.x supported PHP 5.3.  The ::class keyword was introduced in PHP 5.5.  Hence the Bundle::Entity alias syntax was popular early on just to avoid the need for typing out the fully qualified class name. You still see legacy stuff using it.  It's actually a Doctrine thing.  Nowadays I can't think of any reason not to use the ::class keyword.  PHP has come a long ways in the last ten years or so.

Comment: in addition to @JulienB., I also prefer using `SomeEntity::class` as it's easier to refactor using IDE. As far as I remember default symfony plugins doesn't support such option with `AppBundle:SomeEntity`